# What breaks a working $_SESSION on another page?

Tags: php

I have a weird problem. Which, I was using $_SESSION to show login errors to user. It was working with no problem. Few days ago, I have changed my host from a Plesk host to a cPanel host that runs safe_mod off. Somehow my $_SESSIONs at login page doesn't work. I test $_SESSION on index page and it works OK and it show nothing wrong with working of $_SESSION function. Both page included same session starter page.

Also nothing works on login page when my functions file included. (sessions, post items, classes, functions etc. nothing.) But everything works on index page even if functions file included. What's happening here? What can be the reason?

PS: I am using UserCake for members system. My server doesn't allow me to turn PHP errors at htaccess level and nothing seems with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Also nothing seems relevant at my error logs.

Edit: We succeeded to show errors using

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 8191); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

thanks to @J A but no errors seems.

Comment: "Somehow my $_SESSIONs at login page doesn't work"
messages?

Comment: Is `session_start()` present on every page?

Comment: how do you know it "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Sebas because page doesn't echo the session element.

Comment: could we see the starting code of your not working pages please?

Comment: of course! this lines are on my config page which is required at all pages including login page:     
    `// Initialize session
    session_id();
    session_start();`

Comment: breaks how? session is blank on the new page? Check that the session ID is remaining constant.

Comment: @MarcB yes session is blank and also my $_POST item is blank when I required functions file.

Comment: What exactly is this "functions file"? Is it clearing out the session? I assume you have done a `var_dump($_SESSION)` before and after the inclusion of this file?

Comment: @xy_ That file really disturbs me :) Could you please try the output of `var_dump($_SESSION)` immediately after `session_start()` and then after you've included all the files? Then you know if something's wrong

Comment: @xy_ Wait what, so sessions are working?

Comment: @rudi_visser we have discussed it with J A on chat. It is weird more than I thought. No errors but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one of the following solutions.

1. Put session_start(); on top of the pages you are accessing $_SESSION from.
2. Check your php.ini, you can set session autostart to 1 if you don't want to follow the other solution.

Comment: I am sure nothing wrong with starting session. Everything happens when I include functions page to my login page. Same functions page doesn't break my index page.

Comment: So, am I right assuming that you already have session_start on login page(s)?

Comment: Could you provide some relevant codes please from your function page?

Comment: I can show you whole page. Do you want any specific part of it?

Comment: This page has only occurance of session in destroySession function. Can you provide login page as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11888/discussion-between-j-a-and-xy)

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is silly.... But I think you have missed session_start(); on the top of your login page

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

Or what I guess is you must have used same page for login and logout. Therefore the session is being unset or destroyed due to misconfiguration. If it is so, check the code once or seperate the files for login and logout...

Answer (score 0):

add [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) right at the top of the file

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```